# How I get a string which is between two characters in bash script?

Tags: bash

I want get a string which is between two characters in bash script. For example;
AAA_Ubuntu-bbb, in this string I want to get "Ubuntu" as string. How I do it?

Comment: Before sending the question, make sure there is an algorithm underlying on the answers you may get. I don't think there is now, because many questions pop to me: want to get the word after first `_`? before last `_`? 2nd word? penultimate word? Just Ubuntu?

Comment: I have a lot of strings. I want to get these strings's some parts in bash script. The example which I said, I want to get the word after "_" before "-" . Thanks.

Comment: ok. after _ and before -? First _ and first -?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var=AAA_Ubuntu-bbb
string=${var#*_} # remove before _
string=${string%%-*} # remove after -
echo "$string"
```

See the section of the `bash` man page on *Parameter Expansion* for explanations of these operators.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the portion of the string you want is enclosed between `_` and `-` and does not contain such characters, `cut` provides an easy solution. Define a function like this:

```
function extractName {
    cut -d _ -f 2 <<< "$1" | cut -d - -f 1
}
```

and use it in your code like:

```
name=$(extractName "AAA_Ubuntu-bbb")
echo $name
```